# Return a single array of data from given data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my sample data

```
const data = [{"amount": "600,000", "cover": null, "id": "1", "img": "636e56de36301.1.png", "make": "bmw", "model": "bmw", "name": "APA", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "6"}, {"amount": "300,000", "cover": null, "id": "2", "img": "63723574a81ce.1.png", "make": "ferrari", "model": "ferrari", "name": "CIC", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "3"}, {"amount": "450,000", "cover": null, "id": "3", "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png", "make": "audi", "model": "audi", "name": "Mayfair Insurance", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "4.5"}]
```

and here is the code am using to return the array for id 3.

```js
const data = [{"amount": "600,000", "cover": null, "id": "1", "img": "636e56de36301.1.png", "make": "bmw", "model": "bmw", "name": "APA", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "6"}, {"amount": "300,000", "cover": null, "id": "2", "img": "63723574a81ce.1.png", "make": "ferrari", "model": "ferrari", "name": "CIC", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "3"}, {"amount": "450,000", "cover": null, "id": "3", "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png", "make": "audi", "model": "audi", "name": "Mayfair Insurance", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "4.5"}]

const id = ['3']

const provider = data.reduce((prv, item) => {
    if(id.includes(item.id)){
      return prv 
    }
    return prv
 });
console.log('This is provider' ,provider);
```

Unfortunately, the return am getting is data with an id of 1

Output:

```
 This is provider {"amount": "600,000", "cover": null, "id": "1", "img": "636e56de36301.1.png", "make": "bmw", "model": "bmw", "name": "APA", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "6"}
```

can someone tell what am doing wrong please

Comment: Could you please clarify what data you would like to return ? A single array of data yes, but with what data in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to return only an object you can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) but currently, you're doing it a little bit wrong way.

1. You need to pass an initial value to the `reduce()` if it's not then the `reduce` picks the first element of the array as the initial value and starts iterating from the second element. so when condition(s) are false it returns the first element of the array. so you need to be careful with it.
2. You need to return `item` here `if(id.includes(item.id)) return item` not `prev`.

Here is the solution with `.reduce()`

```js
const data = [{"amount": "600,000", "cover": null, "id": "1", "img": "636e56de36301.1.png", "make": "bmw", "model": "bmw", "name": "APA", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "6"}, {"amount": "300,000", "cover": null, "id": "2", "img": "63723574a81ce.1.png", "make": "ferrari", "model": "ferrari", "name": "CIC", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "3"}, {"amount": "450,000", "cover": null, "id": "3", "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png", "make": "audi", "model": "audi", "name": "Mayfair Insurance", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "4.5"}]

const id = ['3'];
const provider = data.reduce((prv, item) => {
  if(id.includes(item.id)){
    return item 
  }
return prv
}, {});

console.log(provider);
```

Also You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const data = [{"amount": "600,000", "cover": null, "id": "1", "img": "636e56de36301.1.png", "make": "bmw", "model": "bmw", "name": "APA", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "6"}, {"amount": "300,000", "cover": null, "id": "2", "img": "63723574a81ce.1.png", "make": "ferrari", "model": "ferrari", "name": "CIC", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "3"}, {"amount": "450,000", "cover": null, "id": "3", "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png", "make": "audi", "model": "audi", "name": "Mayfair Insurance", "policy": "Motor Insurance", "rate": "4.5"}]

const id = ['3'];
console.log(data.filter(it => id.includes(it.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is not working because you're using the Array.reduce() method incorrectly. The reduce() method is used to reduce an array to a single value, not to filter out values from the array.

To filter out the data with the id of 3, you can use the Array.filter() method instead. Here's how your code would look with the filter() method:

```
const data = [
  {
    "amount": "600,000",
    "cover": null,
    "id": "1",
    "img": "636e56de36301.1.png",
    "make": "bmw",
    "model": "bmw",
    "name": "APA",
    "policy": "Motor Insurance",
    "rate": "6"
  },
  {
    "amount": "300,000",
    "cover": null,
    "id": "2",
    "img": "63723574a81ce.1.png",
    "make": "ferrari",
    "model": "ferrari",
    "name": "CIC",
    "policy": "Motor Insurance",
    "rate": "3"
  },
  {
    "amount": "450,000",
    "cover": null,
    "id": "3",
    "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png",
    "make": "audi",
    "model": "audi",
    "name": "Mayfair Insurance",
    "policy": "Motor Insurance",
    "rate": "4.5"
  }
];

const id = ['3'];

const provider = data.filter(item => id.includes(item.id));
console.log('This is provider', provider);
```

This should output the following data:

```
[
  {
    "amount": "450,000",
    "cover": null,
    "id": "3",
    "img": "63723726cb1df.1.png",
    "make": "audi",
    "model": "audi",
    "name": "Mayfair Insurance",
    "policy": "Motor Insurance",
    "rate": "4.5"
  }
]
```